# One-liner for Setting Global Default Options for Unix/Linux Commands - Best Practices

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I consistently run the ruby `sudo gem install mygem` command with these two options on my production system:

`sudo gem install mygem --no-ri --no-rdoc`

I do that to save a little on space and on how long it takes to setup the documentation.  Is there a way (other than hardcoding them into the bin/gem file) to say 'always run this command with these options'?

I figure someone might have a neat little one liner to insert this into the appropriate file with unix/linux somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your home directory there should be a .bashrc file or something similar that gets sourced at each bash session.

Put this in there at the end.

```
function gemi {
    sudo gem install $1 --no-ri --no-rdoc
}
```

This is simple but you'd be calling the function "gemi" rather than the sudo gem command.
You'd call it like

```
gemi mygem
```

Intercepting those commands and replacing them with a wrapper function is a little complicated as far as passing arguments and such.

I am unfamiliar with ruby and the gem command but you may want to look at the man page

```
man gem
```

And see if there are environment variables for doing such things like how the Linux/Unix command grep uses GREP_OPTIONS environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can add this to your `$HOME/.gemrc` file:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

and then run `gem` as:

```
sudo gem install mygem
```